# Make content blocks (which already have dynamic content inside them) appear/not appear for person depending on recipient values?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dynamic-content

Is it possible to embed content builder HTML block inside JavaScript-like if statements?

Like this:

'If recipient has A field, show this block'

'Else: Do not show this field'

Answer (score 0):

If your content blocks are html content blocks or dynamic content blocks, you can use ampscript if else conditions.

```
  %%[ SET @field = field//Assuming the field your trying to set is in the sendable DE
       IF @field == "fieldvalue" THEN]%%
       %%=ContentBlockbyId("your content block id")=%% //This will also open up a browse where you can select the block and it will populate the id.
%%[ELSE]%%
//Do nothing
%%[ENDIF]%%
```